# Foursquare venue score/rating

Tags: foursquare

Does anyone know how I can get a venue's score/rating (e.g. 9.0/10) using the Foursquare API?

I am connecting via Userless Access.
https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#userless

The JSON blob that I get when I request venue details does not seem to include the score/rating.
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is worth noting, first of all, that not all venues have ratings. A rating is only calculated in certain situations, like if there is enough sentiment data about a venue to start calculating a rating and if the venue is not a user's home.

However, if a venue does have a rating calculated and you're making a request with a recent version of the API (make sure you have a v param set from within the last few months), it will be returned in the JSON from the API as follows, when you make a call to `/venues/<ID>`:

```
{
  response: {
    venue: {
      ... // Other data about the venue will surround this, of course
      rating: 7.18
    }
  }
  ... // The response's metadata will also be here
}
```

So, basically you want to check `response.venue.rating`.

Comment: Is there a way to have it returned from /venues/search? call?